# Extract filename and extension in js

Tags: javascript

Need a method in JavaScript to extract a filename and extension.

Example: 
`/vagrant/modules/americabuy/tranzilaNotifications/class/../../../a_tranzila/log/tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47.json`

returns array: `["tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47","json"]`

Comment: show your current code

Comment: If I add I wouldn't ask...

Comment: You should try by yourself first then

Comment: Oh, then it is good if u show your code and ask if there is any better alternative..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `split()` function combined with `pop()` to get the file full name (name + extension) and detect the separation between your file name and extension with `lastIndexOf()` :

```js
var str = '/vagrant/modules/americabuy/tranzilaNotifications/class/../../../a_tranzila/log/tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47.json';

function fileNameAndExt(str){
  var file = str.split('/').pop();
  return [file.substr(0,file.lastIndexOf('.')),file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('.')+1,file.length)]
}

console.log(fileNameAndExt(str));
```

Answer (score 11):

**In Node.js**

```
var path = require('path');

function getFilenameAndExtension(pathfilename){
    return [path.parse(pathfilename).name, path.parse(pathfilename).ext];
}
```

**In JavaScript**

```
function getFilenameAndExtension(pathfilename){

  var filenameextension = pathfilename.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  var filename = filenameextension.substring(0, filenameextension.lastIndexOf('.'));
  var ext = filenameextension.split('.').pop();
  
  return [filename, ext];

}
```

**Result**

```
getFilenameAndExtension("/vagrant/modules/americabuy/tranzilaNotifications/class/../../../a_tranzila/log/tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47.json");
//Result -> ["tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47", "json"]
```

It works too if the filename have more than one ".". For example:

```
getFilenameAndExtension("../log/tranzila.2018-01-09.08-58-47.json");
// Result: ["tranzila.2018-01-09.08-58-47", "json"]
```

Comment: It wont work with file like ".bashrc" where the filename is ".bashrc" itself with no extension.

Comment: Or files with no extension

Answer (score 0):

No need to complex Things.
You have a `split(" ")` method in Javascript that does what you want.

```
var str = '/vagrant/modules/americabuy/tranzilaNotifications/class/../../../a_tranzila/log/tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47.json';

var file = str.split('/').pop();
var fileAndExtensionArray = file.split(".");  // This is ["tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47","json"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short `String.prototype.match()` solution:

```js
var filepath = '/vagrant/modules/americabuy/tranzilaNotifications/class/../../../a_tranzila/log/tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47.json',
    result = (m = filepath.match(/([^/]+)\.([^.]+)$/)) && m.slice(1,3);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

var filepath='/vagrant/modules/americabuy/tranzilaNotifications/class/../../../a_tranzila/log/tranzila_2018-01-09_08-58-47.json';

var filename=filepath.split("")[filepath.length-1];

var extension=filename.split(".")[filename.length-1];